# Missing VC_MFCSupport

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 recently. Today, when I tried to load C++ Win32 Console Application project, I have got the following error:

> Project 'Test' could not be loaded because it's missing install
> components. To fix this launch Visual Studio installer with the
> following selections: VC_MFCSupport

I reinstall Visual Studio with all checked checkboxes, but unfortunately, I got the same error.

Screenshootes:
[.NET section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myawb.png),[Compilers, build tools, and runtimes section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1agy.png),[SDKs, libraries, and frameworks section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB0JM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click [Repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to repair VS.

When you finish it, close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, delete any `Debug`,`Release`,`x64` folder under the solution folder, project folder. Then, reload the project again.

**Also**, you could try to create a new c++ project to test whether the issue happens again.